# Hto convert pandas df into dict based on repeated rows (row has to be key)

Tags: pandas, dictionary

I want to ask Hto convert pandas df into dict like I show below:
I have df like this:

```
col1   col2
"a"   12
"a"   2
"b"   34
"c"   9
"c"   45
```

and I need dict like this:

```
d = {"a":[12, 2], "b":[34], "c":[9, 45]}
```

Anyone give me some tips?
Kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First aggregate to `list`s and then convert output to `dict`:

```
df.groupby('col1')['col2'].agg(list).to_dict()
```